# How to redirect power-shell output with a tcl-file?

Tags: tcl, exec, stdout

I am trying to call a power-shell file (test.ps1) out of a tcl-file. What I tried so far:

The power-shell file works without problem when calling stand alone (Windows PC) while the power-shell shows different output messages in the opened power-shell window.

Now I would like to call the same power-shell file (test.ps1) via a tcl-file (from Quartus application). This works when I simply call:

```
exec "D:/temp/test.ps1"
```

but what does not work is the fact that no outputs are shown from the power-shell file and the application (Quartus) freeze for the time the power-shell is running in the background. When the ps1-file terminates I do see all output in the tcl-file shell again. I tried to use following tcl-file command in order to show the output messages:

```
exec "D:/temp/test.ps1" >@stdout &
```

### The error which I get:

```
Error:channel "stdin" wasn't opened for writing while executing
```

### **Question:**

Any idea why I get this error and how to avoid it in order to see the outputs from the power-shell file?

Comment: How is the tcl program invoked? When you say "works from windows explorer" and "see all output", what exactly do you mean? Do you get a powershell window? Does that pop up when execed from Tcl? You might try explicitly adding `<@stdin` but that may not help.

Comment: @glennjackman adding <@stdin does not work. I have updated my question pls see above again.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this from wish or tkcon?

Comment: @DonalFellows No from Quartus